# How to add complications by default in wearOS android

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, watch-face-api, android-wear-complication

Developer.android says:

void setDefaultSystemComplicationProvider (int watchFaceComplicationId, 
                int systemProvider, 
                int type)

but does not works for me.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about how this "does not work" for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a beginner Android developer and a lack of community support and tutorials available for the Wear OS platform I was struggling to set complications on Wear OS by default. I have somehow managed to make that method work for me with a few adjustment to my code. I would like to share to whom it may help.
This is the method i have used:

```
private void initializeComplications() {
    Log.d("complication", "initializeComplications()");

    mActiveComplicationDataSparseArray = new SparseArray<>(COMPLICATION_IDS.length);

    ComplicationDrawable leftComplicationDrawable =
            (ComplicationDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_complication_styles);
    leftComplicationDrawable.setContext(getApplicationContext());

    ComplicationDrawable rightComplicationDrawable =
            (ComplicationDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_complication_styles);
    rightComplicationDrawable.setContext(getApplicationContext());

    ComplicationDrawable topComplicationDrawable =
            (ComplicationDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_complication_styles);
    topComplicationDrawable.setContext(getApplicationContext());

    mComplicationDrawableSparseArray = new SparseArray<>(COMPLICATION_IDS.length);
    mComplicationDrawableSparseArray.put(LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID, leftComplicationDrawable);
    mComplicationDrawableSparseArray.put(RIGHT_COMPLICATION_ID, rightComplicationDrawable);
    mComplicationDrawableSparseArray.put(TOP_COMPLICATION_ID, topComplicationDrawable);

    // Set default complication
    // This time we don't create a setting screen so we need to set it here
    setDefaultSystemComplicationProvider (
            LEFT_COMPLICATION_ID,
            SystemProviders.STEP_COUNT,
            ComplicationData.TYPE_SHORT_TEXT);

    setDefaultSystemComplicationProvider (
            RIGHT_COMPLICATION_ID,
            SystemProviders.WATCH_BATTERY,
            ComplicationData.TYPE_SHORT_TEXT);

    setDefaultSystemComplicationProvider (
            TOP_COMPLICATION_ID,
            SystemProviders.DATE,
            ComplicationData.TYPE_SHORT_TEXT);

    setActiveComplications(COMPLICATION_IDS);
}
```

and lastly I have called it in:

```
public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(DigitalPrayerTimes.this)
            .setAcceptsTapEvents(true)
            .build());

    // TODO: Step 2, intro 3
    initializeComplications();
}
```